# Windows Authentication : Which users are allowed

Tags: active-directory, windows-authentication, iis-10, windows-server-2016

Windows Authentication, Windows Server 2016 (or any version really)

When this is turned on in IIS10 this just authenticates against Active Directory, the user does not necessarily need to be a user on the server that IIS is sitting on right ?

Sorry for the dumb question

Comment: That's correct. Authentication is just the step to tell if a user is valid or not. So when you use Windows authentication on a domain joined IIS server, all valid AD users are allowed to authenticate. To control which authenticated users can move on and access the web pages, the next step is called authorization, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/understanding-iis-url-authorization#configuring-url-authorization

Comment: you can refer to this link: [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication). Although it says to the contrary, it proves that it ok. you can use Windows authentication when your IIS 7 server runs on a corporate network that is using Microsoft Active Directory service domain identities or other Windows accounts to identify users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this just authenticates against Active Directory

Yes and no. It's called "Windows Authentication" and not "Active Directory Authentication" for a reason. It allows the website to authenticate any account that the server is capable of authenticating.

If the server is joined to a domain, then that can be an Active Directory account on the same domain or on any domain that domain trusts.

But it can also be a local account that only exists on the server itself - and that is true whether or not the server is joined to an AD domain.

Comment: Yeah that is what was weirding me out. We have several other domains connected in a trust. So I wondered if it would just check active directory against the domain the server was actually sitting on or all of them. Thanks for your answer.